# the delete operator in javascript

Tags: javascript, webkit

I would like to ask questions about 'delete' operator in Javascript

Why

```
delete window.document; // returns false
```

but

```
delete navigator.geolocation; // returns true
```

I try other properties of `navigator` and it still returns `true`

I have checked the IDL in webkit, 
`document` and `navigator` are both of readonly, 
and they dont have DontDelete attribute
but why I can delete one but not for the other???

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to understand the `delete` operator, wrap your mind around the [javascript spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) section 11.4.1

There are several cases where the operator should evaluate to `true` without mutating any objects.

From 8.12.7, the operator checks checks an internal `[[Configurable]]` property of the property descriptor to enforce readonly properties.