# Javascript delete mechanics

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [the delete operator in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6173308/the-delete-operator-in-javascript)

I have the following code. I don't understand why the second delete fails.

Also, I noticed that the foo function still exists even after I assigned something else to foo.

Is there a way to reference the function?
(suppose I'd want a `bar2=foo()` to behave like the `bar` assignment).

```
> function foo(){var bar=0; return function(){return bar++;}}
undefined
> bar = foo()
function () {return bar++;}
> bar()
0
> bar()
1
> delete bar
true
> foo = foo()
function () {return bar++;}
> foo()
0
> foo()
1
> delete foo
false
```

Thanks

Comment: On my side `delete foo` returned `true`. Can't reproduce your error. I runed code like: `function foo(){var bar=0; return function(){return bar++;}}
bar = foo();
bar();
bar();
delete bar;
foo = foo();
foo();
foo();
delete foo;`

Comment: I was using javascript console. I'm reading from http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/ that it might the problem.

Comment: @VyacheslavVoronchuk http://jsfiddle.net/Sxnaw/4/ The output is `true`, `false` which is in line with what the OP described.

Comment: It was trouble in Firebug (delete worked fine there), your Fiddle works as intended.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`delete` only works on deleteable properties. Functions declared like this:

```
function f(){
}
```

are not deleteable.

Try using this syntax for the original function declaration:

```
foo = function (){var bar=0; return function(){return bar++;}}
```

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/Sxnaw/

You can go through this article for an in depth explanation of deleteable and non deleteable properties: http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/

Comment: What's the difference between `function f() {}` in scope of `window` and `window.f = function() {}`?

Comment: @VyacheslavVoronchuk the first is defined at parse time, the second at runtime. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/336868/247441).

Comment: @VyacheslavVoronchuk One is defined as a property of the global with the `DontDelete` attribute, the other is created as a property of the global without the `DontDelete` attribute (since it is explicitly created via property assignment). You can read up more on it [here](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/)

Comment: @AntonStrogonoff That is true, but it is not the key factor here.

Comment: 2Asad, I upvoted your answer, it was trouble on my side, not your answer.

Comment: @Asad Thanks for correction, you're right. Parse-time vs. runtime definition does not determine the ability to be deleted. Linked article is nice, too.

Comment: Thanks Asad, it's a little clearer now. The question that remains is, shouldn't the DontDelete attribute be removed when I do a new assignment?

Comment: @user1586156 No, because the attribute is set when the property is *created*, not when its value is changed. You created the property in a way that makes it non deleteable, and non deleteable it shall stay, regardless of what syntax you use to change its value.